# 90s (or earlier) book: mixed lot of prisoners have to come together on an uncolonized prison planet

Tags: story-identification, books

Not much to go on and I'm just looking for maybe a direction to look in.  I read this book almost twenty years ago (in the 90s) in Lincoln, Nebraska, and it's been in the back of my mind ever since.

All I remember is a bunch of people were sent to a planet and I believe a lot of them were prisoners. But a mixed lot.  It wasn't colonized ever so they had to come together to live, against the world and its inhabitants.

Not much to go on but I remember it being a good book.

Comment: Same as [this one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39004/a-book-from-the-60s-or-70s-about-a-crashed-spaceship-and-their-colony) maybe? There is a Project Gutenberg [etext](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/22549).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catteni_Series (first book published in 1995)

Comment: Any of [these covers](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?1073) look familiar?

Answer (score 4):

Possibly Barry B. Longyear's [*Infinity Hold*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0595092748), first published in 1989.

[image: book cover, man with rifle in front of a structure in a sandy landscape]

From one of the reviews on the Amazon link above:

> In 2115 Bando Nicos is a twenty-seven year-old inmate of "The Crotch",
>   the Union of Terran Republics' prison for incorrigibles in Greenville,
>   Mississippi. Like many other prisons, The Crotch is shut down and the
>   entire population deposited on the planet Tartaros, named for the
>   lowest level of hell, the galaxy's dumping ground for the unwanted.
>   Soon after they are abandoned in the sandy desert of Tartaros, the
>   seventeen thousand-plus population is reduced to three thousand. The
>   remaining "sharks" decide they must band together if they want to
>   survive, and elect a leader who makes Bando the first police officer
>   of the newly-christened Razai gang. With the help of pre-teen killers,
>   homicidal maniacs, and political dissidents, Bando makes up the
>   brutally simple Law of the Razai as they travel in search of a place
>   of refuge. In between trials and fights for survival against the gangs
>   already in residence, Bando and his compatriots must think about the
>   meaning of justice, and Bando examines his own heart to see if he is
>   worthy of the trust placed in him.